# How to access array elements inside JSON in nlohman json in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, json

I have following JSON file

```
{
    "list" : 
    {
            
            "type"                  :   "school",
            "students"              :   [
            {
                "name"              :   "root",
                "marks"             :   "100"
            },
            {
                "name"              :   "joe",
                "version"           :   "100"
            }]
    }
}
```

So in code I have parsed this JSON file and assigned this JSON object to JSON::student. So I am able to assign first element to string like this :

```
 std::string type = student["list"]["type"];
```

and it works. SO similarly I want to do for "name" and "marks" in "students" array. How can I do that?

Comment: You just iterate them like ordinary arrays. `const std::string& name0 = student["list"]["students"][0]["name"]`

Comment: @SergeyA Doesn't work

Comment: Explain `doesn't work` with [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over all the elements with **iterators**

```
std::string const str = "{ \"list\" : { \"type\" : \"school\", \"students\" : [ "
                        "{ \"name\" : \"root\", \"marks\"   : \"100\"}, "
                        "{ \"name\" : \"joe\",  \"version\" : \"100\" } "
                        "] } }";
nlohmann::json const js = nlohmann::json::parse(str);

nlohmann::json const& ja = js["list"]["students"];
for (auto it = ja.begin(); it != ja.end(); ++it) {
  // For each individual element (root, joe, ...)
  if (it->contains("name")) {
    std::string const name = (*it)["name"].get<std::string>();
    // Do something with the name
  }
  if (it->contains("marks")) {
    std::string const marks = (*it)["marks"].get<std::string>();
    // Do something with the marks
  }
  if (it->contains("version")) {
    std::string const version = (*it)["version"].get<std::string>();
    // Process version
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but in my case , it is not entering the for loop somehow. Any idea why?

Comment: Hey @Nilesh How did you test it? Could you put an output after the declaration of `ja`: `std::cout << ja << std::endl` and similarly inside loop `std::cout << *it << std::endl`? `ja` should output the term in square brackets `[ ... ]`, the array itself while `*it` should output the elements `{...}` then. I have tested it inside Visual Studio 2019 and it works for me if you just copy and paste the code above.

Comment: Try this code the way it is by copy and pasting it, inserting the output as suggested above. If this works and if you have modified the code to fit your needs feel free to share your code in the form of a screenshot or similar...

Comment: `std::ifstream student_file("/home/root/student.json", std::ifstream::binary);
student_file >> student;
std::string name1;

nlohmann::json const& ja  =  student["list"]["students"];
for (auto it = ja.begin(); it != ja.end(); ++it)
{
  if (it->count("name") != 0)
  {
    name1 = (*it)["name"].get<std::string>();
  }
}`

This is how my code is. I am reading from a json file. But here it is not entering the for loop even once

Comment: @Nilesh I have just tried your code and for me it works. If I put `std::cout << name1 << std::endl;` at the end of it it outputs `joe`. Are you sure that there went nothing wrong with reading the file (e.g. reading the wrong file or trying to read a non-existing one)? As already mentioned output `ja` and `*it` and let me know what is in them.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to output ja and it is NULL. I don't understand why. That's why it doesn't enter for loop also. And I don't think file reading went wrong because if i do 
`std::string type = student["list"]["type"];`
and then print type it giving right output. In your program you are reading from a file or you are reading from a string as shown in your answer?

Comment: @Nilesh I tried both and both works for me. Copy and paste my code and check if it works like that. Which compiler and operating system are you using?